# Which ROSversion would you recommend to beginners?

Tags: ros, rosversion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello.

Write for the first time.

Which ROSversion and UbuntuVersion would you recommend to beginners?

I want to make a robot using ROS.
I would like to use (Kinect, RealSense, MechanumRobot, LRF, GPS)  at Ros.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278408/which-rosversion-would-you-recommend-to-beginners?/) by [cherrycoke44](https://answers.ros.org/users/33073/cherrycoke44/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Step 1: If you plan to use a specific ROS package, can check its compatibility with a specific ROS distribution from its ROS wiki or github page.

Step 2: After deciding on a ROS distro, from the distribution's wiki page, find out which Ubuntu version it targets. For   example, ROS kinetic is targeted at Ubuntu 16.04.

From my experience, most packages support Indigo and Kinetic

---

Originally posted by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) with karma: 249 on 2017-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-30**:
Indigo and Kinetic are also the LTS versions of ROS. http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions#List_of_Distributions